# why python gives the such an error " float division by zero" while evaluating "log(e,1)"

Tags: python, math, logarithm

I've defined a function which is

```
from math import *

def func(x):

    return log(e,x)
```

Error is short and clear, do you know why python cannot evaluate

```
func(1)
```

,which is equal to ln(1), ?

edit: Since I'm new there, I have posted a silly question, I'm sorry, but now I handled it

Comment: Hypothetically, what do you think log(e,1) should evaluate to?

Comment: You can't use `1` as the base of a logarithm. `log(x, b)` is the exponent that `b` has to be raised to to get `x`. But when you raise `1` to any exponent, the result is always `1`.

Comment: What function did you define?

Comment: can you show us the code of your function please.

Comment: log (x, 1) = log (x) / log (1) that's why you have a division by zero error. Be sure to read the manual

Comment: You have the arguments backwards. The base is the second argument.

Answer (score 2):

@mike_z was right about what he recommended,

I had a piece of backward arguments, in other words I thinked of the function

`math.log(a,b)` or `log(a,b)`

(depending on how you impoted math modulo)

as if a indicates base ,and b indicates the other operand whose logarithm is to be evaluated

but the true approach is that inverse of sentence above is right,

Tank you all!

Answer (score 2):

This is the definition of the `log` function. As mentioned in the comments, your base cannot be `1`.

```
def log(x, base=None): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
        """
        log(x[, base])

        Return the logarithm of x to the given base.
        If the base not specified, returns the natural logarithm (base e) of x.
        """
        pass
```

You can see the below operations:-

```
>>> import math
>>> 
>>> def func(x):
... 
...     return math.log(10, x)
... 
>>> print func(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 3, in func
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
>>> print func(2)
3.32192809489
>>> print func(3)
2.09590327429
>>> print func(4)
1.66096404744
>>>
```